# Why do Ethernet devices not show up in "/dev"?

Tags: networking, ethernet, devices

Generally I have noticed that plugging in a new device in a Linux system causes a new entry to be listed in `/dev` (assuming you have the correct drivers).

For example:

1. When you plug in a new hard drive you get `/dev/sdb`.
2. When you plug in a serial device you get `/dev/ttyS0`.

When I plug in an Ethernet device, why don't I get something like `/dev/eth0`?

Is there a device listing for Ethernet ports?

I know you can see port names using `ifconfig`, I am just wondering if something shows up in `/dev` too.

Comment: See also [Why are network interfaces not in /dev like other devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23199/why-are-network-interfaces-not-in-dev-like-other-devices) on [unix.se]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a good question. The reason is essentially historical; different groups with different goals and priorities added pieces of Unix over time, and the differences among various APIs are a reflection of this history.  I think the original device file concept goes back to Bell Labs, whereas network sockets were added later at UC Berkeley. Bell was trying to create a nice clean maintainable paradigm for AT&T's operations, whereas Berkeley needed to add internet features that didn't fit easily into that paradigm. Technically it would be possible to go back and create a `/dev/eth0` file today (see below), but it would involve rewriting a prohibitive amount of legacy code.

Slight OT: If the subject interests you, consider taking a look at Plan 9, which took "everything is a file" to greater extremes (just don't expect it to have very many modern, usable applications):

http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/plan9.html

> many facilities that under Unix are accessed through various ad-hoc interfaces like BSD sockets, fcntl(2), and ioctl(2) are in Plan 9 accessed through ordinary read and write operations on special files analogous to device files

Comment: thanks for your insight! That really is too bad. To me, it feels like a really odd quirk in an otherwise great device management system.

Answer (score 0):

Hello nowadays the /dev directory is populated by udev, a daemon that reads the /sys directory, and create those files. If you want to use fdisk and gdisk, you are forced to use devices found in /dev. And to see the the tty and pty used. I think BSD allocates an ethernet interface in /dev, where you can write and read to.

Answer (score 0):

Not so long ago Ethernet devices *did* appear as /dev/eth0, /dev/eth1 and so on. There are still applications that expect to find them there, but are now disappointed and sometimes unusable. Fortunately not too many.