# Which of these hardware devices are not listed in the /dev directory?

Tags: drivers, kernel, hardware, udev, devices

(1) Mouse

(2) Video adapter

(3) Network adapter

(4) Webcam

(5) Hard drive

(6) USB drive

I feel like all of them is listed except for the network adapter , Is that correct ?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**

```
$ ls /dev/input/mou*
/dev/input/mouse0  /dev/input/mouse1  /dev/input/mouse2

$ ls /dev/dri/card*
/dev/dri/card0

$ ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0

$ ls /dev/sd* /dev/sg* /dev/hd*
/dev/sda  /dev/sda1  /dev/sda2  /dev/sda3  /dev/sda5  /dev/sda6  /dev/sg0  /dev/sg1
```

**Why? See these related questions**

- [Why do Ethernet devices not show up in “/dev”?](https://askubuntu.com/q/306594/26246)
- [Why are network interfaces not in /dev like other devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23199/12209)
- [Is there a device file in the /dev directory that represents the wireless adapter?](https://superuser.com/q/564113/98606)