# What's the "/sys" directory for?

Tags: filesystem, sysfs, directory-structure

A while ago I noticed this directory that I had not ever seen before, `/sys`. I researched a bit and read that "modern Linux systems" often have this directory, and that it manages devices. I thought that was what `/dev` was for. I can't seem to find a whole lot of information about this directory, other than what I mentioned, and this, quoted from [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview) page:

> /sys is a virtual file system that can be accessed to set or obtain
> information about the kernel's view of the system.

I have been running Trusty for a while now, and never noticed it before, which is why I find it a little strange. Would someone please fill me in? What is the difference between `/sys` and `/dev`? When did Ubuntu start using this directory, and why? Thanks.

Comment: `/sys` has been around for over [a decade now](http://lwn.net/Articles/54651/).

Comment: Sidenote , perhaps will be useful to other users: /proc and /sys directories ,being virtual filesystems, will disappear once the the computer is shut down. If you ever mounted a hard drive with Linux on another OS you'll see that those directories are empty.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`/sys` is *old*. It was introduced before the Linux kernel reached 2.6 (back when there was a 2.4/2.5 split). Since [the first Ubuntu release used a 2.6 kernel](https://askubuntu.com/a/517140/158442), *every* version of Ubuntu has had a `/sys`.

`/dev` contains the actual device files. It does not provide access to all devices that the kernel knows of (such as ethernet devices, for one - [Why are network interfaces not in /dev like other devices?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/23199/70524), [Why do Ethernet devices not show up in "/dev"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/306594/158442)). It is an interface to the device itself - you write to the device, read from it, etc.

`/sys` is an interface to the kernel. Specifically, it provides a filesystem-like view of information and configuration settings that the kernel provides, much like `/proc`. Writing to these files may or may not write to the actual device, depending on the setting you're changing. It isn't only for managing devices, though that's a common use case.

More information can be found in [the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sysfs.txt):

```
Top Level Directory Layout
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The sysfs directory arrangement exposes the relationship of kernel
data structures. 

The top level sysfs directory looks like:

block/
bus/
class/
dev/
devices/
firmware/
net/
fs/

devices/ contains a filesystem representation of the device tree. It maps
directly to the internal kernel device tree, which is a hierarchy of
struct device. 

bus/ contains flat directory layout of the various bus types in the
kernel. Each bus's directory contains two subdirectories:

    devices/
    drivers/

devices/ contains symlinks for each device discovered in the system
that point to the device's directory under root/.

drivers/ contains a directory for each device driver that is loaded
for devices on that particular bus (this assumes that drivers do not
span multiple bus types).

fs/ contains a directory for some filesystems.  Currently each
filesystem wanting to export attributes must create its own hierarchy
below fs/ (see ./fuse.txt for an example).

dev/ contains two directories char/ and block/. Inside these two
directories there are symlinks named <major>:<minor>.  These symlinks
point to the sysfs directory for the given device.  /sys/dev provides a
quick way to lookup the sysfs interface for a device from the result of
a stat(2) operation.
```

---

For example:

- One way of setting the brightness of a laptop monitor is:

  ```
  echo N > /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
  ```
- To get the a network card's MAC address:

  ```
  cat /sys/class/net/enp1s0/address
  ```
- To get the current CPU scaling governors:

  ```
  cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor
  ```

And so on...

Comment: @muru: What if I want to remove one of these files which is consuming a lot of memory? I wrote a device driver which was buggy(may be) which went into a loop and continuously wrote to some file in /sys/devices directory. Also, if I accidentally delete a wrong file what would be the impact?

Comment: @BhavikShah you don't remove anything from here - these files don't actually exist. You'll have to remove the module involved.

Comment: @muru Can one remove/modify/add any file from/to/in `/sys` directory? Hope so you'll answer because I'm in some trouble.